# How can I transform SQL to show start and stop dates and show every day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| Person | State | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joe | blue | 2/4/2020 |
| bob | red | 12/1/2019 |
| bob | black | 12/3/2009 |
| joe | blue | 2/4/2018 |
| joe | red | 12/1/2015 |
| mary | black | 12/3/2009 |

I have a table set up as shown above. I want to transform this to the following

| Person | State | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | blue | 2/4/2020 |  |
| bob | red | 12/1/2019 |  |
| bob | black | 12/3/2009 | 11/30/2019 |
| joe | blue | 2/4/2018 | 2/3/2020 |
| joe | red | 12/1/2015 | 2/3/2018 |
| mary | black | 12/3/2009 |  |

After this, I want to have one line for every calendar day that a Person is in a given state. If there is no end date, the days in a given state should stop at the current date.

How can I do this with SQL only?

Comment: I'm about to sign out, so will try to return tomorrow if you don't get an answer, but you can likely do it with a windowing function. i.e. lag(startDate) over (partition by person order by startDate desc) Should get you the penultimate startDate

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: Shall we guess that `EndDate` arises whenever someone enters an _altered state_? Can a person transit multiple states in one day, e.g. a _sublime_ trip from solid to gas to plasma? Is a _line_ like a _row_ in a table?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the window function `lead()` in concert with `dateadd()` would be a good option

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,EndDate = dateadd(day,-1,lead(StartDate,1) over (partition by Person Order by StartDate))
 From YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
Person  State   StartDate   EndDate
bob     black   2009-12-03  2019-11-30
bob     red     2019-12-01  NULL
joe     red     2015-12-01  2018-02-03
joe     blue    2018-02-04  2020-02-03
joe     blue    2020-02-04  NULL
mary    black   2009-12-03  NULL
```

**EDIT - To Expand Into Daily**

We take the query above and add `IsNull(...,convert(date,getdate()))` to trap the end dates.  Then we create an ad-hoc calendar table and perform a simple join.

```
Select A.*
      ,B.D
 From (
        Select *
              ,EndDate = IsNull(dateadd(day,-1,lead(StartDate,1) over (partition by Person Order by StartDate)),convert(date,getdate()))
         From  YourTable A
      ) A  
 Join (
        Select Top (datediff(day,'1999-12-31',getdate()))
               D=dateadd(day,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),convert(date,'1999-12-31'))
         From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
      ) B on D between StartDate and EndDate
 Order By Person,D
```

**Returns 10,210 rows**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like to use recursive CTEs for expanding data.  It is pretty simple in your case:

```
with cte as (
      select person, state, startdate,
             lead(dateadd(day, -1, startdate),
                  1,
                  convert(date, getdate())
                 ) over (partition by person order by startdate) as enddate
      from t
      union all
      select person, state, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select person, state, startdate
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4c182903e7be93532304594ac75009c) is a db<>fiddle.